# How to get client side absolute path of selected file in php

Tags: php, file-upload, path, filepath

I want to know whether there is anyway to get the client side absolute path of selected file!

`$_FILES['xml_file']['tmp_name'];` This also provides path of selected file but its server side path... Its result is something like this `C:\xampp\tmp\php2679.tmp`

I want `C:\Users\Sami\Desktop\data\myfile.xml` where my actual file is placed.

Because I want this actual path to use again for fetching and saving etc automatically (by code).

Comment: i may say something wrong but i thinks is not possible for obvious security reason.

Comment: @Yanis-git ... I strongly think you are right...

Answer (score 0):

you may try `echo realpath($_FILES['xml_file']['name']);` on your php.

then the output will be:

`C:\Users\Sami\Desktop\data\myfile.xml`

Answer (score 0):

When you click the **browse button** it chooses the file.  When you click the **submit button**, the entire file is being sent from the browser to the web server, and PHP is indeed putting the entire file in the php servers temp directory.  **Then, your script gets called.**

So when you try to get absolute path from `$_FILES['xml_file']['name']` or `$_FILES['xml_file']['tmp_name']` or `realpath($_FILES['xml_file']['name'])` you will get the path on server.

The solution to this problem would be to simply copy the file somewhere, and not ask for the file upload again.  You'll need to be sure that where ever you copy it to on your web server, that the server has permissions to do so.  Usually that involves giving write permissions for the user which the web server runs as (usually user 'apache' or 'nobody' for apache based servers)  to a special directory you've created for the purpose.

Copy is available in PHP.    https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Your only trick will be what to name it so you can find it again for the second request, and deciding what directory to put it into.